# Private ethereum blockchain mining on a Raspberry Pi - is it possible?

Tags: raspberry-pi, blockchain, raspbian, ethereum, geth

I am trying to write a private ethereum blockchain lab for both the college class I teach and a MeetUp group at the financial services firm where I work during the day. Using ethereum and geth on RPi 3B+. Can mining be performed on a  Pi’s running Raspbian (32 bit).

I’ve been working with two dates articles that don’t appear to be current with the geth and java script console commands and options. Does anyone have any good pointers to an ethereum private blockchain on a raspberry pi for running smart contracts?

Comment: I've been following a mooc on Udemy last year (paid by the enterprise I was working with) and from what I remember, I was quite easy to deploy an Ethereum blockchain. If you do not find what you are looking for, maybe an option could be to create your own docker environment and to pull it from your raspberry.
If you can read french, I can send you a document describing my former work and how my friend deployed the eth blockchain and how we used it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some pretty good guides out there for setting up your own node (I use [this one](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8)). For a Raspberry Pi 3B+ you can use two types of packages when downloading from https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ (choose tab linux, you should download the latest Geth & Tools):

- armV7 (32bit)
- arm64 (64bit)

They both work for me. You should use Proof of Authority for consensus in a private network. The guide above describe how to create a private PoA network. Some of the commands may be outdated due to updates to the geth client, but you should be able to work it out yourself. If you need any specific pointers, feel free to comment.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll take you up on your offer when I get stuck! That’s one of the three posts / articles I’ve been using.